# How can I create a bot in Amazon Lex for getting weather update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, weather

I am trying to get weather update. The Python code is working well but I am unable to embed it into Amazon Lex. It is showing received error response.

```py
from botocore.vendored import requests
    # using openweathermap api 
    api_address = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=__api_key_here__&q='
    city = input("Enter city >> ")

    url = api_address + city

    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    formatted_data = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
    desc_data = json_data['weather'][0]['description']
    print(formatted_data)
    print(desc_data)
    # print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure api is running perfectly python code.
- Depends on the next state you need to keep type as ElicitSlot or ElicitInten
- If you are using lambda as backend for the lex, we need send the response in a below format.
- You can refer the link for the Lambda response formats
  [Lambda response formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

```js
        {
      "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
          "contentType": "PlainText",
          "content": "Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
        },
        "responseCard": {
          "version": integer-value,
          "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
          "genericAttachments": [
              {
                 "title":"card-title",
                 "subTitle":"card-sub-title",
                 "imageUrl":"URL of the image to be shown",
                 "attachmentLinkUrl":"URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
                 "buttons":[ 
                     {
                        "text":"button-text",
                        "value":"Value sent to server on button click"
                     }
                 ]
              } 
          ] 
        }
      }
    }
```